# Найди кого-нибудь(-)то

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Найди кого-нибудь-то.

> Найди кого-нибудь то.

> Найди кого-нибудь-с.

> Найди кого-нибудь с

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По [правилу Розенталя (п. 5)](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=74), нужно в первом варианте опустить дефис, а во втором нет:

*Найди кого-нибудь то*;

*Найди кого-нибудь-с*.